# Request object's unique identifier - django or django rest framework

Tags: python, django, request, django-rest-framework

Whenever a request goes to a server, I think there would be a unique identifier for each request object. But I couldn't find how to access that unique identifier.

I have already read the docs for [django HTTPRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) and [django-rest-framework Request Object](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/).

Please Explain, How to get request object's unique identifier, If there is one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `No`. There is no unique identifier for each and every request something like `request-id`.We have to generate it from server or generate from client side and pass to server via `Header`. Also there is no `time` in `HTTP request` according to [w3c](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html)